# Optimize code without removing thread lock

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to put a ripple simulation ontop of an already buisy app. Right now the cpu runs at about 11ms on the lowest processors. All the code in it so far runs on the main thread.

I am hoping that it is possible to put the ripple simulation entirely on another thread.

The simulation is based on the apple [GLCameraRipple project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html). Basically it creates a tesselated rectangle, and calculates the texture coordinates. So in an ideal world the texture coordinates, and ripple simulating arrays would all be on a different thread.

The update function I am working with right now looks like this. It does sorta leverage GCD however it gains no speed from doing so due to to the sync. Without the sync however the app would crash because swift arrays are not thread safe.

```
var rippleTexCoords:[GLfloat] = []
var rippleSource:[GLfloat] = []
var rippleDest:[GLfloat] = []
func runSimulation()
{
    if (firstUpdate)
    {firstUpdate = false; Whirl.crashLog("First update")}

    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)     
    let block1: (y: size_t) -> Void = {
    (y: size_t) -> Void in

    objc_sync_enter(self)
    defer { objc_sync_exit(self) } // */ This will actually run at the end

    let pw = self.poolWidthi
    for x in 1..<(pw - 1)
    {
        let ai:Int = (y    ) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
        let bi:Int = (y + 2) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
        let ci:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x
        let di:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x + 2
        let me:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x + 1

        let a = self.rippleSource[ai]
        let b = self.rippleSource[bi]
        let c = self.rippleSource[ci]
        let d = self.rippleSource[di]

        var result = self.rippleDest[me]
        result = (a + b + c + d) / 2.0 - result
        result -= result / 32.0

        self.rippleDest[me] = result
    }
    //Defer goes here
}

dispatch_apply(Int(poolHeighti), queue, block1);

/*for y in 0..<poolHeighti {
   block1(y: y)
}*/

let hm1 = GLfloat(poolHeight - 1)
let wm1 = GLfloat(poolWidth - 1)
let block2: (y: size_t) -> Void  = {
    (y: size_t) -> Void in

    objc_sync_enter(self)
    defer { objc_sync_exit(self) } // */

    let yy = GLfloat(y)
    let pw = self.poolWidthi
    for x in 1..<(pw - 1) {
        let xx = GLfloat(x)
        let ai:Int = (y    ) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
        let bi:Int = (y + 2) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
        let ci:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x
        let di:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x + 2

        let a = self.rippleDest[ai]
        let b = self.rippleDest[bi]
        let c = self.rippleDest[ci]
        let d = self.rippleDest[di]

        var s_offset = ((b - a) / 2048)
        var t_offset = ((c - d) / 2048)

        s_offset = (s_offset < -0.5) ? -0.5 : s_offset;
        t_offset = (t_offset < -0.5) ? -0.5 : t_offset;
        s_offset = (s_offset >  0.5) ?  0.5 : s_offset;
        t_offset = (t_offset >  0.5) ?  0.5 : t_offset;

        let s_tc = yy / hm1
        let t_tc = xx / wm1

        let me = (y * pw + x) * 2
        self.rippleTexCoords[me + 0] = s_tc + s_offset
        self.rippleTexCoords[me + 1] = t_tc + t_offset

    }
}
        dispatch_apply(poolHeighti, queue, block2)

        /* for y in 0..<poolHeighti {
         block2(y: y)
         } *///

        let pTmp = rippleDest
        rippleDest = rippleSource
        rippleSource = pTmp
    }
```

Is there any way to force this code to constantly run on a different thread? Or somehow get it to go faster?

I dont konw if it was possible but if it is I would have these arrays on the following thread:

Main:

- rippleVertices
- rippleIndices

Secondary: (These are never read or written on the main thread)

- rippleSource
- rippleDest

On both threads:

- rippleTexCoords (Read on main thread, written on secondary thread)

If these conditions are followed then the runSimulation method could possibly be run on the second thread without issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory is dirt cheap these days.  Why not save the result in an extra work array?  Read-only access to rippleDest and rippleSource won't need sync.  You'll only need to use the lock when copying the computed results to rippleDest, thus reducing locking time to the bare minimum.

For other speed gains, I'd start by moving initialisation of all of indices ai, bi, ci, di, me, out of the loop, since they are only incremented by 1 for each iteration.  This would save at least a half dozen operations per node even after compiler optimisation - that's as many operations as the useful work done by the procedure.  You probably wont't get a 50% improvement from that, but something closer to 10-15%, which is not bad.

Comment: This is actually a brilliant idea! I dont know exactly how to achieve it but I will play around with it. Thankyou!

Comment: Maybe you could use a semaphore to start the ripple computation, then set a flag when that is done.  Then check/wait for the flag before rendering from the main thread.  This kind of arrangement would eliminate the need to use a work copy altogether.

Answer (score 2):

That obj_sync prevents your code from running on multiple threads, so dispatch_apply will just slow things down.

Comment: I agree, and I sort of mention this in my question although not using the exact details. The focus of this question is improving the speed of the code to match what can be done in objective-c